# Sequence $x_n$ converges in ($\mathbb{R}, d$) $\iff$ $x_n$ converges in ($\mathbb{R}, d^*$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $\rho: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $\rho(z) := \frac{z}{1+|z|}$. We further define $d$,$d^*: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $d(x,y) := |x-y|$ and $d^*(x,y) := |\rho(x) - \rho(y)|$.

I have already shown that $d$ and $d^*$ are metrics over $\mathbb{R}$. Now what I need to show is the following:

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Show that $x_n$ converges in $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ $\iff$ $x_n$ converges in $(\mathbb{R}, d^*)$

My approach so far: Let $x$ be the limit of $x_n$ in $(\mathbb{R}, d)$. Then by definition it is true that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq N$: $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$. Now let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, then we have

$$|\rho(x_n) - \rho(x)| = |\frac{x_n}{1+|x_n|} - \frac{x}{1+|x|}| = \frac{|x_n + x_n|x| - x - x|x_n||}{1 + |x| + |x_n| + |xx_n|} \leq \frac{|x_n - x| + |x_n|x| - x|x_n||}{1 + |x| + |x_n| + |xx_n|}$$

Now we know that an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ exists, such that for all $n \geq N$: $\frac{|x_n - x| + |x_n|x| - x|x_n||}{1 + |x| + |x_n| + |xx_n|} < \frac{\varepsilon + |x_n|x| - x|x_n||}{1 + |x| + |x_n| + |xx_n|}$.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Your denominator is wrong.

Comment: @Tobsn $(1+ |x|)(1 + |x_n|) = 1 + |x_n| + |x| + |x| |x_n| = 1 + |x_n| + |x| + |xx_n|$. Since every term is non-negative: $|1 + |x| + |x_n| + |xx_n|| = 1 + |x| + |x_n| + |xx_n|$.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I was too hasty.

Comment: Ok, so here is a more constructive advice. How about adding and subtracting $|x|x$ in the second term of the final numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** $\rho$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(-1,1)$. Therefore, for a sequence $(x_n)$ of real numbers, and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} x_n = x \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \rho(x_n) = \rho(x)$$